# How to use HTTPS / SSL with self signed certificate on Mgt Development Environment

Tags: magento, ssl, docker, https

I got the Mgt Development Environment docker image up and running for HTTP traffic and wanted to test https/ssl traffic - that is what I did:

1. created new self-signed certificates here: http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/
2. downloaded the .cert and .key file
3. copied the content of the .key-file to "Private Key" textbox on /domain/view/sslCertificate/1
4. copied the content of the .cert-file to "Certificate" textbox on /domain/view/sslCertificate/1
5. left the "Intermediate CA" textbox empty
6. Click "Save Certificate"
7. restarted complete docker container

But when I try to open my https://project.dev the browser shows an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

All other configuration is untouched.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between Step 6 and 7 it is required to click the button "Install" (small arrow-down icon) on /domain/sslCertificates/1.

I missed this and thought after "Add New" everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

i am the developer behind the MGT Development Environment.

By default it's working fine without any problem.

Another customer reported a similiar problem wich was caused by a conflict with vagrant.

> Blockquote

Thanks for your response, it was probably a strange conflict with Vagrant,
as I have removed all Vagrant references and finally had a working
solution. The error was ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (in Chrome). Caused probably
by my DNS resolving which went wrong and did not point to the docker
instance but the VirtualHostX Vagrant instance.

Resetting the hostfile and removing tabs from definitions of localhost ->
ip mappings did some help as well mapping the docker to port 8080 instead
of 80. Strange thing is, I can access the docker instance only at port 80,
while the mapping is 8080 but this has more to do with Docker for Mac and
other OSX issues so let’s move on